# Why synonym for table in linked database not in DBA_DEPENDENCIES?

Tags: oracle, package, dependencies, dblink, synonym

We have DB1 with public link to DB2.
Packages refencing tables from DB2 could be selected from DBA_DEPENDENCIES with proper REFERENCED_LINK_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE, REFERENCED_NAME and REFERENCED_OWNER.

We have LINK in DB1 created for table in DB2. But it is not found in DBA_DEPENDENCIES.

SELECT *
FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE
REFERENCED_LINK_NAME IS NOT NULL